# How to reduce root EBS volume size of an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got my website running on an EC2 instance with 1 EBS of 50 GB attached as root volume. My requirement is to reduce the size of this EBS volume to 20 GB from currently 50 GB. I tried lot of ways like creating an image and launching a new instance with EBS volume as 20GB but in the end launch fails with message saying that volume size can only be increased from current size (i.e. 50GB) and cannot be reduced.

May I know if there is any workaround to handle this issue. I have data in root volume but I do not require whole bunch of 50GB space on my root volume. Please assist.

Thank you,

Comment: You can't reduce root EBS volume. You should just redeploy everything in new volume, that will reduce mistakes of moving the mount volume around and render the system unbootable . In addition, I don't see why you should reduce the volume : 1.  Larger EBS volume will give you better throughput (50x3 iops = 150iops) .  2. The storage cost is negligible to reduce from 50GB to 20GB.  Btw, this question is offtopic to stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a new volume and copy everything across, making sure that the volume remains bootable.

Then: Stop instance, detach volume, attach new volume, boot.

At 10c/GB/month, the reduction of 30GB will save you $3/month. It isn't worth your time.